# Azure Virtual Network Subnet

Tags: azure-virtual-network

We are using the IoT hub and Azure functions. Both are not exposed to public and working on private environment.

We have the VNet with the range of **x.x.111.x** to **x.x.114.x**

We have the **Private-end-point (x.x.111.x)**  to connect the **IoT hub** to the **virtual network**. The **Azure functions** VNet integration was enabled and the selected **Private end point range is (x.x.112.x)**. But the **Inbound Private** End point is configured as **x.x.111.x**.

We have a script which will listen on IoT hub Build-in-endpoints. We have tested the script in one of the **VM(x.x.111.x)**. Its writing the data to the Data lake Containers which was there in the same VNet. When we deploy the same script into the Azure Functions, its not writing any data to the destination.

***Our Question:***
To establish the communication between recourses is required **same subnet** or we can establish the connection with **same VNet**?

***Thanks for your support in Advance***

Comment: They can be part of same VNet to have communication. By default, Azure allows communicate between subnets in a same VNet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our Question: To establish the communication between recourses is
> required same subnet or we can establish the connection with same
> VNet?

Azure Allow communication between Vnet of same subnet by default and also Vnet of Different subnet as well.

**Case 1** : Communication within same subnet.

**All the devices in the same subnet can communicate directly with one another without going through any routers.**

**case 2** : Communication between different subnet.

**NICs connected to subnets (same or different) within a VNet can communicate with each other without any extra configuration**